# How to search tweets with certain emoji

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler, emoji

I am doing a project using Python for emoji recommendation system. The first step is collecting data from twitter. Specifically, I need tweets using top popular emojis. I am thinking about crawling the website or use the twitter API. But I didn't see anywhere in twitter document about how to search with certain emoji(maybe using its unicode, for example, U+1F602).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Twitter Rest API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) specify a call to [search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

> Returns a collection of relevant Tweets matching a specified query.

The query param `q` should be UTF-8 encoded so try passing the UTF-8 encoding of the emojis you are looking for.

Edit: I just went over tweets with emojis in them, they are images, so it doesn't look like you can search on them.

Comment: Yes, but there is no help on how to search only tweets with EMOJI!

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but I don't think it works :(

Answer (score 0):

I manage to so with the help of this article 
https://medium.com/@mroth/how-i-built-emojitracker-179cfd8238ac#a5d7

Instead of searching `u'\U0001F602'`, I searched `1F602`
and I started the following getting results:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print api
query = '1F602' # u'\U0001F602'   
print query
max_tweets = 10
search = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets)
for status in search:
    print status.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching by UTF-8 encoding did not work for me but I had luck simply copying and pasting the emoji in the query. [I think this became supported in 2017](https://thenextweb.com/apps/2017/04/28/twitter-now-supports-emoji-search-absolutely-needed/).

the updated code looks like this:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print api
query =  #U+1F601   
print query
max_tweets = 10
search = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets)
for status in search:
    print status.text
```

I'm not sure why this works and using the encoding doesn't. If you try to search for the encoding, it searches for the literal string.